# Extracting sentence from multiple paragraphs

Tags: r

I need to extract the first sentence from every paragraph in a written text. I also need to preserve the paragraph structure so that the first sentence is its own paragraph.

I need to use R for this one.

I know I have to add a loop function, but I don't know how to.

Thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Imran Luqman! Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Thank you, @r2evans. But I was thinking of only maintaining the first sentence of different paragraphs in a text. For example: 

1st paragraph: My name is xxx. I am 100 years old. I have a house. 
2nd paragraph: I have a wife. She is 90 years old. She has a mansion. 

My desired output would be; 
1st para: My name is xxx. 
2nd para: I have a wife.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that every sentences are split with `.` and every paragraphs are split with `\n`. For example,

```
dummy <- c("first sentence. blablabla.
       first sentence2. blablablabblah.")
```

Then by using `stringr::str_split`,

```
sapply(str_split(dummy, "\n", simplify = TRUE), function(x) str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1])
```

You can get

```
          first sentence. blablabla.            first sentence2. blablablabblah. 
                    "first sentence"                "           first sentence2"
```

If  your input is vector of paragraphs,

```
dummy <- c("first sentence. blablabla.","first sentence2. blablablabblah.")
sapply(dummy, function(x)str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1])

   first sentence. blablabla. first sentence2. blablablabblah. 
             "first sentence"                "first sentence2"
```

## Code for your text.

```
dummy <- c("Now, I truly understand that because it's an election season expectations for what we will achieve this year is really low. But, Mister Speaker, I appreciate the very constructive approach that you and other leaders took at the end of last year to pass a budget and make tax cuts permanent for working families." , "So I hope we can work together this year on some priorities like criminal justice reform.So, who knows, we might surprise the cynics again.")

lapply(dummy, function(x)str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1])

[[1]]
[1] "Now, I truly understand that because it's an election season expectations for what we will achieve this year is really low"

[[2]]
[1] "So I hope we can work together this year on some priorities like criminal justice reform"

unlist(lapply(dummy, function(x)str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1]))
[1] "Now, I truly understand that because it's an election season expectations for what we will achieve this year is really low"
[2] "So I hope we can work together this year on some priorities like criminal justice reform"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Park. But I had an error saying simplify=T is an unused argument. If I deleted that one, the output will be: 

$`first sentence. blablabla.`
[1] "first sentence" " blablabla"    

$`first sentence2. blablablabblah.`
[1] "first sentence2" " blablablabblah"

Comment: @ImranLuqman Did you use `str_split` or `strsplit`? I'm sorry that this code may confusing. May you try `sapply(stringr::str_split(dummy, "\n", simplify = TRUE), function(x) stringr::str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1])
`?

Comment: In both code, if error still occurs when using `stringr::str_split`, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so soon. 

First, I used str_split, but they couldn't recognise the function. So, I used strsplit. It worked, but then the error message for the simplify=T came up. 

I'll give it a go with the new code and will update you.

Comment: @ImranLuqman I'm really sorry for unkind explanation. You need `stringr` package. Try `install.packages("stringr")` and then load package with `library(stringr)`.

Comment: Hey @Park. It's somewhat successful. 

But, I found out that the written text has to be in 1 straight line. My text example was on multiple lines. So, they gave me a mad output. Is there any way to rectify this?

Comment: @ImranLuqman If your example is not too long, can you paste that text to your question?  Then I can edit a code for your text.

Comment: text <- "Now, I truly   understand   that   because   it's   an   election   season expectations for what we will achieve this year is really low. But, Mister Speaker, I appreciate the very constructive approach that you and other leaders took at the end of last year to pass a budget and make tax cuts permanent for working families." , "So I hope we can work together this year on some
              priorities like criminal justice reform.So, who knows, we might surprise the
              cynics again."

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Park. I really appreciate it. 

So, for the first paragraph, I would like to have "Now, I truly understand that because it's an election season expectations for what we will achieve this year is really low."

For the second paragraph: "So I hope we can work together this year on some priorities like criminal justice reform."

Comment: @ImranLuqman I didn't notice that your paragraph is paragraph(it's long). Instead of `sapply`, `lapply` will give you a better result. I add code for your text.

Comment: Yeah, and that's just a small part of the text. There are more paragraphs. 

Thanks again, @Park

Comment: Hey @Park. Sorry, I didn't notice that you have added the code. 

It words perfectly! Thank you for your help. Appreciate it.